# Install php-mcrypt on CentOS 4.4

Tags: centos, mcrypt

I need to get php-mcrypt running on a CentOS 4.4 box, so I can use a PHP mcrypt module (as per company policy).

I have tried installing it via yum, as I did with a CentOS 5.5 box, with no luck.

```
[root@server www]# yum install php-mcrypt
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
No Match for argument: php-mcrypt
Nothing to do

[root@server www]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 4.4 (Final)
```

I have very little experience with CentOS, so I don't really know what to do next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CentOS 4.x, php-mcrypt is in the **centoplus** repository.  It may be installed by using the following command.

```
yum install php-mcrypt --enablerepo=centosplus
```

**CAUTION!!**  The version of `php-mcrypt` installed on your server must match the version of php (or, at least, be compiled against the same libraries) on your server.  Installing the `php-mcrypt` RPM from the **centosplus** repository will result in a major version change of PHP -- you will be upgraded from 4.x.x to 5.1.x.  This may or may not be a problem for your applications.

Alternately, you might like to use [the Atomicorp yum repository](http://www.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/4/i386/RPMS/).  They have PHP 5.2, and are frequently updated for the latest versions of the LAMP stack.

Comment: Thanks, I will bug one of our SysAdmins to get the box updated with the new repos.